# How to Update and Add Data for multiple document At a time in FireStore Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want push Data for diffent document at a time in FireStore android.How to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Use Batch writes
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=1#batched-writes

```
WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC'
DocumentReference nycRef = db.collection("cities").document("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, new City());

// Update the population of 'SF'
DocumentReference sfRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
batch.update(sfRef, "population", 1000000L);

// Delete the city 'LA'
DocumentReference laRef = db.collection("cities").document("LA");
batch.delete(laRef);

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: i want update multiple document in a single collection. Then i want to check if document is exist.

Comment: @Balasundark use `task.isSuccessful()` in OnCompleteListener. It will return true only if all writes was successful. If one of writes fails, whole batch will be canceled.

Comment: i am Using Single DocumentReference in a For loop and I need Check document is exist then I update the document.. what is the Solutions?

Comment: @Balasundark you should not loop queries as they are working on background thread. Use complete listeners.

Comment: i want to update the data in complete listeners.. how to handle it?

Comment: @Balasundark can you be more specific? I don't have an idea for what you are trying to do with your document.

Comment: I want to do for two things. One is wants to set  Data into Multiple Document for Single  Reference  and Second one is update Data if Document exist for Multiple Document in Single Reference.

Comment: Finally, I Fix my problem, am Initially Update query in my Reference if Failed I am Adding Set Query into Fail listener..Thanking you @GoCrafter_LP